# meaning of "punching sb right in the GD mouth"

Tags: meaning-in-context

https://www.google.com/amp/s/pagesix.com/2017/12/01/chris-pratt-warns-fans-about-potential-predator-imposter/amp/

Apparently , somebody is impersonating Chris Pratt. He has warned his fans about this.

One part I am not 100% sure.

He says:"If I found out who it is , I'll have their account shut down and would like to punch them right in the GD mouth".

I searched GD. Does it mean "God damn"? I am not 100% sure.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it does.

Profanities are often abbreviated or slightly altered, both in written and spoken language. The reader/listener will understand what the speaker/writer means without them explicitly using the questionable expression.

Answer (score 0):

*[Goddamn](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/GD)* (or *god damned*, or some other variation) is correct - it's a common bowdlerisation.